# Category shortcut keys in Outlook 2013/2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to expand the category shortcut key choice beyond the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for Outlook 2013/2016. A registry hack maybe?